# Akka.DependencyInjection doesn't throw error when can't resolve dependencies

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-6.0, akka.net

I'm using the DI in the following way:

```cs
 _actorSystem.ActorOf(
    Supervise(PropsWithDI<MessagePublisherActor>()), MessagePublisher.ActorName);

private Props PropsWithDI<T>(params object[] args) where T : ActorBase
    => DependencyResolver.For(_actorSystem).Props<T>(args);
```

If somehow there is a Constructor parameter which isn't added to the DI container, it simply doesn't create the Actor, which is normal of course but I would expect an error or something.

Am I using it wrong or is this a missing functionality of Akka.NET Akka.DependencyInjection.

Comment: Hi @Lóri Nóda, this is definetly a bug, thanks for bringing this into our attention. We will be working on this ASAP.
An issue is opened here: https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/issues/5734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like indeed you can at least catch the error on runtime which helps a lot.
I ended up with something similar:

```
.WithSupervisorStrategy(new OneForOneStrategy(receivedException =>
                {
                    _logger.LogError("Eror: {exception}", receivedException);
                    return Directive.Escalate;
                }));
```

This article has more information about how to set up the supervisior:

https://getakka.net/articles/concepts/supervision.html

```
var childProps = Props.Create<EchoActor>();

var supervisor = BackoffSupervisor.Props(
    Backoff.OnStop(
        childProps,
        childName: "myEcho",
        minBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
        maxBackoff: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        randomFactor: 0.2)
        .WithAutoReset(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        .WithSupervisorStrategy(new OneForOneStrategy(exception =>
        {
            if (exception is MyException)
                return Directive.Restart;
            return Directive.Escalate;
        })));

system.ActorOf(supervisor, "echoSupervisor");
```

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the code I've found that this is actually a design choice.

The ActorSystem is designed with fault isolation in mind, it is designed so that any fault happening on the individual actor level would not propagate up to the application layer and crash the application, just like in any operating system, you don't want a fault in a single process to bring the whole operating system down.

To achieve this, actors are started asynchronously inside their own bubble to create a high degree of fault isolation. It is actually done in 2 steps:

1. An empty actor holder is returned by the `ActorOf()` method, this holder contains the `MailBox` and `ActorCell`. `ActorCell` contains the Props needed by the system to re/create the actor as needed.
2. A `Create` system message is enqueued into the Mailbox, triggering the actual Actor instantiation.

This is essentially a "bubble" where the actor code lives, any exception thrown by any code at step 2 onward are blocked from propagating to the application layer and instead propagated up the chain of actors above it, letting them decide on what would happen to the faulting actors. Since the DI exception happened on step 2 of the process, the exception would never reach the code that actually calls the `ActorOf()` method and instead be propagated up to the guardian actor and be logged as an error in the log.